# Match an unique string to a shorter unique string

Tags: php

Let say I have to manage 1,000,000 phone numbers which are in 12-digit format. Certainly, they are distinguish. Now I want to assign to each number a shorter string (7 alphanumeric - case sensitive characters) that must be also distinguish. What would be the best solution using Php?

Comment: So basically, you want to "compress" the phone numbers?  Is that right?  Do you want to be able to convert between both formats?  Or do you just want a short (unique) "hash" of them?

Comment: Would something like [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) be valid?

Comment: Actually I don't need to re-convert backwards to phone numbers. After extracting the shorter strings I can store in database for use later.

Comment: uniqid() doesn't solve this. Maybe we cannot limit length of output strings to a specific value (is 7 here). Also, it doesn't use a string (say phone number) as only input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's base_convert() function to change integers into strings.

From integer to a-z0-9 base 36 string: `$shortString = base_convert($phoneNumber, 10, 36);`

From base 36 string to integer: `$phoneNumber = base_convert($shortString, 36, 10);`

If that's not short enough and you want to use the full gamut of a-zA-Z0-9 characters, you'll need to use a custom function to convert to base 62. There are some great ones at http://php.net/base_convert.

Comment: Tried. This seems great. Base 62 (0-9A-Za-z) results in very very short strings that then can be extended to 7 characters if need.